# Umbraco connection reset error

Tags: connection, umbraco, umbraco6

We encounter "connection reset error" when trying to save a content that contains some words i.e. "or", "find", etc. The problem is not related to the length, content or something etc. except from these reserved words. Do you have any idea on how to fix this problem? 
We use : **Umbraco v6.0.6** (Assembly version: 1.0.4898.16909)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could sounds like a service or something that blocks the request because it thinks its a sql injection or something.. do you have anything installed on the server?

Comment: There is only MSSQL database, but it is not currently in use (the web site connected to a database on another server). I am sure that the only difference between the problem and the other situation when I can save the content is a word "or". What do you mean with "anything installed?"

Comment: I once had to install an umbraco instance on a server which had a program that hijacked all requests to check for sql injections. It then blocks the request if it looked suspicious. The word "or" is a common word for sql injection, so maybe it could be something like this. If not, I have no clue :) (btw, did you look for any errors in the console in dev tools?)

Comment: I checked again but there is no error in Firebug console. On the other hand the post is like below on Network section in Firebug:
http://.../41424/webservices/legacyAjaxCalls.asmx/GetSecondsBeforeUserLogout

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue.
In our case, IPS blocked the connection when it detected "dangerous" words.

Comment: In our case, IPS was killing requests which contained words, which it evaluated as sql injection. So things like and or select caused connection to be dropped